# Animate elements while scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

Nowadays,there is trend of animating page elements.So.I'd come with an idea of animating elements while we scroll down to the page.For achieving that I'd taken a little bit help of JQuery and rest is Html and CSS.

```
<div class="noanimate imgleft">  
</div>
<div class="noanimate imgright">
</div>
```

The image left and image right classes represent floated elements to the right and left, respectively.
no animate elements are hidden by default using zero opacity, along with transition properties for the animation.

After creating Html part.let's give its css:-

```
.noanimate{
    display:inline-block;
    opacity:0;
    transition:0.55s ease-in;
}
.imgleft.noanimate{
    left:-20%;
}
.imgright.noanimate{
    right:-20%;
}
```

In this css As u see we had moved elements to minus 20% left and right.So that they come like floating.
And now comes the most important J Query part.We have to check whether our element is visible in view port before adding our animation to them.
So,I had done my code in parts.

A:- First find all elements on which we have to add animation & window scrolling function.

```
var $section=$(".noanimate"),
$window=$(window);
$window.on('scroll',function(){
    $section.each(function(i,elem){
        if($(elem).hasClass('view')){
            return ;
        }
        else {
            checkView(elem);
        }
    }); 
});
```

B:-Now for checking element to visible in viewport is done by two methods like

1.Window scrolling.

2.Element container.

If element container is within window scrolling then element is visible.I'd had fulfilled this dilemma by this code.

```
function checkView(elem){
    var viewTop=$(window).scrollTop(),
    viewBottom=viewTop+$(window).height(),
    sectTop=$(elem).offset().top,
    sectBottom=sectTop+$(elem).height();

    if(sectTop>=viewTop && sectBottom<=viewBottom){
        switchClass(elem);
    }
    function switchClass(elem){
        $(elem).removeClass('.noanimate').addClass('view');
    }
}
```

You could always check browser versions in JavaScript to force these elements into view when CSS3 transitions are not possible.

Here is the Fiddle link:-[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rumman123/s1o3c4f6/43/)

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

guys
i just made few modification because as it was working only for the scroll down but when you perform scroll up nothing happens as the images are already been loaded

so here is just my try to do little better

you can check this

```js
 $(function(){
     var $section=$(".noanimate");
     var $window=$(window);
     $window.on('scroll',function(){
       $section.each(function(i,elem){        
           checkView(elem);         
       });
     });

     function checkView(elem){
       var viewTop=$(window).scrollTop();
       var viewBottom=viewTop+$(window).height();
       var sectTop=$(elem).offset().top;
       var sectBottom=sectTop+$(elem).height();

       if(sectTop>=viewTop && sectBottom<=viewBottom){
         switchClass(elem);
       }else{
        switchClassBack(elem);
       }
       function switchClass(elem){
         $(elem).removeClass('.noanimate').addClass('view');
       }
       function switchClassBack(elem){
         $(elem).removeClass('view').addClass('.noanimate');
       }
     }
 });
```

and here is the jsfiddle for this demo

**[Demo For better](http://jsfiddle.net/s1o3c4f6/44/)**

Comment: Ya.U had made it better